# passing/changing a variable outside timer events in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, timer

How do you pass a variable from inside a timer event to outside the timer event ?

```
MyVar = false;
setTimeout(function() { myVar = true;}, 10000);
if(MyVar == true){
     console.log("Hello World");
}
```

how to change timerStop from false to true after 30 seconds ?

```
render() {

const timerStop = false;

let button;

  if(timerStop == true){
         button = <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit2} ><Button loading={this.state.loading2} >Button 2</Button></Form>;
  }else{
         button = <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit1} ><Button loading={this.state.loading1} >Button 1</Button></Form>;
  }

return (
<Layout>
  <p></p>
       {button}
  <p></p>
</Layout>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since setTimeout operates asynchronously, your code won't work as your if block will always be executed before the functon you passed to setTimeout.

A solution would be to place your if block inside your timer function so it will only be executed after your timer triggers and not immidiately.

Comment: the problem is that i am not allowed to do that ...i have node,react code that does not allow me to do that.

Comment: @alin It's hard to give a concrete answer without a real code example. So I think you should include the pertinent code in your question.

Comment: // how to change timerStop from false to true after 30 seconds ?
render() {

const timerStop = false;

let button;

  if(timerStop == true){
         button = <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit2} ><Button loading={this.state.loading2} >Button 2</Button></Form>;
  }else{
         button = <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit1} ><Button loading={this.state.loading1} >Button 1</Button></Form>;
  }


    return (
    <Layout>
      <p></p>
           {button}
      <p></p>
    </Layout>
    );
}

Comment: @alin What about putting the timerStop variable in the state of your component? This way, you could use a timeout to set this.state.timerStop to false after 30 and since the state has changed, your component will re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to implement a pub-sub model here. I think there are lot of library out there could help you.

For example this 
https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS

```
myVar = false;
var MY_TOPIC = 'change_value';
PubSub.subscribe(MY_TOPIC, function (msg, data) {
   if(data == true){
     console.log("Hello World");
   }
});

setTimeout(function() { 
   myVar = true;
   PubSub.publish(MY_TOPIC, myVar); 
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Yeah, it's just the idea. If you are good in design pattern, observer pattern may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this code on node/react client side ,but now i got to find a way to keep it on server side so nobody can change value to false ...

```
    state = {
     Timer:false
    };


const timerStop = this.state.Timer;


setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({Timer: true});
}, 10000);
```